# How to populate combobox2 depending on *selected* access database table in combobox1 without writing If statements for each table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I would want to prompt user to select a tool name from combobox1, then out automatically, combobox2 gets filled with tool description and size for that specific tool, which is a column in the selected table.

Currently i have been using the following code, however the problem comes when i would like to update the database and add another table. This would mean adding the code in the application as well. I would like the application to be able to detect that a new tool table has been added and show that automatically without having to code again

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' ADDING TABLE NAMES TO COMBOBOX 1 (TOOL NAME)
    con.Open()
    Dim schemaTable As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})
    For Each dr As DataRow In schemaTable.Rows
        Combobox1.Items.Add(dr.Item("TABLE_NAME"))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Combobox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    'FILLING COMBOBOX 2 (TOOL DESCRIPTION AND SIZE) DEPENDING ON SELECTION IN COMBOBOX 1 (TOOL NAME)

    If Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

        Combobox2.Text = ""
        con.Open()
        Combobox2.Items.Clear()

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from 14_POUND_HAMMER"
        cmd.Connection = con

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            Combobox2.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1))
        End While

        dr.Close()
        con.Close()

    ElseIf Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then

        Combobox2.Text = ""
        con.Open()
        Combobox2.Items.Clear()

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from 3_QUARTER_IMPACT_WRENCH"
        cmd.Connection = con

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            Combobox2.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
        End While

        dr.Close()
        con.Close()

    ElseIf Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then

        Combobox2.Text = ""
        con.Open()
        Combobox2.Items.Clear()

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from ABRASIVE_CUT_OFF_SAW "
        cmd.Connection = con

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            Combobox2.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0))
        End While

        dr.Close()
        con.Close()
```

Comment: Your code appears to be truncated...

Comment: If the first `ComboBox` contains the table name, why can't you just get the `Text` and plug that into your SQL code? Everything else is exactly the same so doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: Don't do `SELECT *` if you only need one column. Always specify the exact column(s) you want to retrieve and don't specify any that you're not going to use.

Comment: Don't add the items to the `ComboBox` one by one like that. Use a `BindingSource` and bind the data reader. See [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?887311) for how.

Comment: Why does each tool have its own table? As @jmcilhinney said, reference 1st combobox for tablename and plug it into the SQL: `Select * from " & ComboBox1`. Eliminate If Then Else and reference to combobox selected row index.